# Github pages no me carga el HTML ni CSS

Tags: github-pages

Hola tengo una pequeña pagina web que realize con HTML y CSS pero el problema es que realize todos los pasos para alojarla en Github pages pero la pagina no carga las imagenes ni el CSS. He modificado los links pero no encuentro el error para que me puedan cargar las imagenes y los estilos de la pagina.

Cuando inspecciono con la consola. Me aparece este error en todos los elementos: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Este es el link al repositorio de Github: [Repositorio de Github](https://github.com/emilyjheredia/Practica-HTML5-CSS3)

Este es el link a la pagina en Github Pages [Github Pages](https://emilyjheredia.github.io/Practica-HTML5-CSS3/)

Comment: Comparte cómo tienes el código para las imagenes porfa.

Comment: Hola comparti la respuesta de como solucione el error

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta a mi duda era simplemente cambiando las rutas de las imagenes y el CSS.

El link de las rutas a las imagenes estaba asi:

```
<img class="foto" src="/Multimedia/IMG_20220710_155433.jpg"
            title="foto Emily Heredia"
            alt="foto Emily Heredia">
```

Y lo cambie eliminando la primera barra inclinada..

```
<img class="foto" src="Multimedia/IMG_20220710_155433.jpg"
            title="foto Emily Heredia"
            alt="foto Emily Heredia">
```